# Where can i get this drawable?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

I need the "Snooze" drawable as in the following image.
Where can i get it?

[image]

Comment: Use Photoshop or other tools to draw a png .

Answer (score 2):

<s>It's not available in the framework</s>(See @User117's answer), but it *is* available in the DeskClock app. To be precise  it's available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_alarm.png).

[image]

(It's hard to see since it's very light)

If you want to clone the DeskClock app then you can run this:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock
```

Answer (score 1):

It is present in the [Android Action Bar Design icon pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) ([ZIP direct download](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20120814.zip)) pack under the name `10-device-access-alarms`.

Comment: Never link to a direct download.

Comment: @poitroae Split it into two links, one to the page, one to the zip

Comment: @Raghav Sood Thanks for the reply.10-device-access-alarms is a clock. I want the sleeping man icon like in the image above.

Comment: @AmJay That appears to be a custom drawable and not part of the pack Google provides. You'll have to make it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Have a look inside SDK directories, entire theme's drawables are downloaded when you install a platform on Android SDK.

This one is present at `<sdk_path>/platforms/android-<version>/data/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_audio_alarm.png` right on your computer, where SDK is installed. Alternate resulotions are in their respective directories as well.

**For the lazy**: you may even try using `android.R.drawable.ic_audio_alarm` directly. If compiler says this resource isn't public, then you can just copy images from SDK directory to project's `res` directory.

Comment: Oh you're right. Completely overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

It's available as a free download from the developer.android.com site. Go to [this link](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html), then download the Action Bar Icon Pack (or download it directly from [here](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20120814.zip)). The icon you seek is located at `/All_Icons/holo_dark/xhdpi/10_device_access_alarms.png`.